# Certificate in 'res' - is it safe?

Tags: android, ssl

I just got my first certificate, and I was trying to reach the URL from android, although it gave me **trust anchor for certification path not found** error. I was browsing for a while until I found a solution, which basically consisted of adding the certificate into /res/raw directory and later on adding it into KeyStore as a Certificate object.

Everything works fine. But I'm a little bit concerned. Isn't it a bit unsafe? I heard of some hacking techniques that allow hackers to extract installed application's contents. It kind of makes sense that the certificate in /res/raw contains only a public key, in which case it would be fine, but I'm afraid that there is more than that. Thanks for replies.

Comment: "I just got my first certificate" -- out of curiosity, where did you get the certificate from? The trust-anchor-not-found message indicates either a self-signed certificate, a new certificate authority, or an authority that has been disavowed by Android (and perhaps other parties on the Internet). "Isn't it a bit unsafe?" -- AFAIK, you should be fine. I don't think that your solution will work if you somehow accidentally put the private key in your app, and so long as it is just the public key, there should be no issue.

Comment: i got it from namecheap via Github student pack. I activated it, set up SSL on my web service and tried to connect without certificate. It gave me that error. So youre saying that if the C in /res/raw was private, then the connection would not work?

Comment: "i got it from namecheap via Github student pack" -- that's odd. I get my certs through them, though not via that student pack. My certs are backed by Thawte, and Android has no problem with them. Namecheap must be using some other root authority for the student pack certs. "So youre saying that if the C in /res/raw was private, then the connection would not work?" -- AFAIK, yes.

Comment: I just tried to connect again without certificate in KeyStore. Im using httpsurlconnection, and it gives me the error stated above. So im either doing something wrong, or its as you said. Maybe there really is a difference between 'student' certificate, and the paid ones.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use 'protect' connection, you have to create key-pair:
public and private.
So, you have to hide private key (usually server-side).
Everytime you create a connection you have to use public key to a client-side.
That is, you can put public key into `/res/raw` in order to use later.
Usually key-pair create protected connection between client and server.